# How to make animations out of a Table of images in Mathematica 7

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

If I have a set of pictures, how can I make it so I can get an animation out of them? In old versions of Mathematica, it was possible to compact them and then double click them so it would show them as sequence(i.e., animation), but I'm now using version 7 of Mathematica and that doesn't seem possible.

How can I do so?

[alt text http://img63.imageshack.us/img63/7972/d2ilrx0vvczls0ntmqsalgp.png](http://img63.imageshack.us/img63/7972/d2ilrx0vvczls0ntmqsalgp.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `ListAnimate` is what you're looking for:

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListAnimate.html

Comment: Thanks. But is it still possible to do the double click thing?